# How to get invocation list of an explicit event in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I can define an event with the following:

```
public event msg_callback event_PingMessage;
```

and get the invocation list of an event with the following:

```
MulticastDelegate event_delegate = (MulticastDelegate)this.GetType().GetField(event_name,
                                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField).GetValue(this);

foreach (var handler in event_delegate.GetInvocationList())
{
    // use handler() here 
}
```

But, if I define my `event_PingMessage` as an explicit event, like:

```
    private msg_callback explicitEvent;
    public event msg_callback event_PingMessage
    {
        add
        {
            explicitEvent += value;
            int i = 0; 

        }
        remove
        {
            explicitEvent -= value;
        }
    }
```

the `MulticastDelegate event_delegate = ...` line throws an exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How can I `.GetInvocationList()` for my explicit events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `explicitEvent.GetInvocationList()`. `explicitEvent` is the equivalent of the field returned by your `GetField(...)` call for a field-like event.